# Coldfusion, using cfqueryparam to filter an email form that is sent to the webmaster

Tags: coldfusion, sql-injection, html-email, csrf

Literally looked everywhere, How can i prevent SQL injection or CSRF from happening with an email form?

The user will fill out an email form, which has various fields in it. The form will then send an email to the webmaster who will then add it to the datasets and database. I have this bit under check, however there is no security at all with it.

So to clarify, the email form constructs an email, and will send the email to the webmaster.

Comment: Thanks for updating this, but it's still vague. For one thing, how the hell does SQL injection have anything to do with sending emails? What do you mean here? What version of ColdFusion are you running (the answer will differ according to what it is: always specify this). It sounds like the question you're asking actually has nothing to do with the bit you detail here, but rather it's more related to "an email arrives which has some data to be entered into the DB, and [some problem you have encountered and cannot resolve despite showing us what you've tried and how it doesn't work]"

Comment: Apologies, still learning. I assumed it was called SQL injection if you put code into an input field that would mess up the web page. i'm running CF10.And the concern isn't what arrives to the webmaster, but rather what a person wanting to break the site may do with the form.

Comment: OK, so you're concerned, for argument's sake, that the baddie puts some JS in the form field, and you don't simply want to output that JS in the body of your email as it might then execute on the recipient's machine when they open the email? I suspect you want to be looking @ `encodeForHtml()` and its ilk: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForHTML

Comment: Yes, that worked! Just to clarify, cfquery and cfqueryparam is strictly for database use?

Comment: Yup. I'll promote that comment of mine to an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you're concerned, for argument's sake, that the baddie puts some JS in the form field, and you don't simply want to output that JS in the body of your email as it might then execute on the recipient's machine when they open the email?

I suspect you want to be looking @ [`encodeForHtml()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForHTML) and its ilk. That will escape anything that could be interpreted as HTML, so it will simply output as content, rather than being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can't execute in an email. Not allowed. CSS can, somewhat.